# Catching textbox 'x' click through knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a textbox in my webpage. I have subscribed to the value changes of the textbox.I get the value change while typing immediately. However, when 'x' in rightside of the textbox is clicked , I do not get any notification.

Html:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchterm, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown' ">
```

View Model:

```
searchterm.subscribe(function (newValue) {
            //do something
});
```

How to get the notification?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using internet explorer. In other browser, this cross doe not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: searchterm, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown','input'] ">
```